# Remove a newline and tabs

Tags: regex, notepad++

We want to change all occurrences of

```
},
{
```

to

```
},{
```

no matter how far they are indented (using tabs).

Notepad++ won't recognize my regexps `},(\t*)\n{` and `},(\t)*\n{`, and I don't know why.

Which is the correct regexp?

Comment: Just use `\s*` as in `}\s*,\s*{`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  \s*(\}\,)[\n\s]*(\{)
```

This should do it.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/rI6jZ0/1

Comment: `\s` includes `\n` and you don't need to escape `{},`

Comment: I removed the \s* at the start because I want to keep the indentation (my fault to not specify correctly what I want), but then it worked like a charm. But: RegExps are still a mystery to me...

Comment: You are on track.A few more and you will be comfortble with them :)

Comment: That's what I am thinking since I started with them in 1999.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to capture anything..

REgex:

```
},\s+{
```

Replacement string:

```
},{
```

`\s` matches any white space character `[\r\n\t\f ]`

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dR4bN1/7)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but you should escape `{` & `}` in Notepad++

```
\},\s*\{
```

Then replace it with `},{`

**\s** *means any white space character `[\r\n\t\f ]`*